# Como executar o uma função cada hora?

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um código simplificado em javascript, sem várias IFS para cada hora e sem usar. Eles devem ser executados nas horas certas... 12h, 13h, 14h... `setInterval` puramente não serve, pq ele executa de acordo com o horário que o usuário abriu a página.

Digamos que eu queira executar uma saudação toda hora sem utilizar `if` para cada hora, posso até usar o `if`, mas não para cada hora separadamente... Isso é uma forma simplificada da pergunta.

```
let horas = new Date().getHours()
alert("Olá!")
```

Comment: Tem noção que isso em JS só funcionará se o usuário ficar com a página aberta no navegador por várias horas? É isso mesmo que precisa?

Comment: setInterval e setTimeout não servirão 100% para o caso, abas que ficam algum tempo sem foco podem interromper (pausar) funções como elas, para economizar recursos do usuário final, sua dúvida soa como um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635). Antes de [edit] a pergunta e para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena fazer o [tour], ler o [mcve] e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Comment: Pode ser que o seu problema não precise ser 100% em tempo real para resolver as situações, ou pode ser ao contrário, dependa 100% de um horário real, vindo do servidor, que dispare ações, por isso soa como um problema XY. Reflita bem sobre a necessidade real, leia os links e revise a pergunta, dessa forma poderemos lhe ajudar de forma mais precisa. Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se baseie nos minutos:

```
setInterval(function () {
    let minutos = new Date().getMinutes();
    
    if(minutos == 0){
         alert('Olá');
     }
}, 1000);
```

Nesse caso, sempre que for o minuto 0 então ele vai executar o código, executando assim 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, etc..

Comment: Utilizando o código acima, sempre em cada hora (12:00, 13:00, 14:00....) sempre haverá penas uma vez por hora que vai entrar no if do minuto == 0, então independente do horário que o usuário entrou, quando der alguma hora com o minuto 0 ele vai executar e depois só na próxima hora e assim por diante.

Comment: Para uma solução bem mais otimizada, ao invés de você executar a função a cada segundo para verificar se é hora cheia, você poderia identificar quantos segundos faltam para a próxima hora cheia e executar somente depois desse tempo e nessa execução já agendar a próxima execução para 1h depois.

Comment: sim @Woss, pode ainda melhorar essa função para ficar mais exata. Show sua dica =)